# Bounce ListView only bottom

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make ListView bouncing only bottom but disable on top? I want to disable only top because look strange on my app.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              destinationImage(),
              contentImage(),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you have to write Custom Scroll Physics:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

class BottomBouncingScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  const BottomBouncingScrollPhysics({ScrollPhysics? parent})
      : super(parent: parent);

  @override
  BottomBouncingScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return BottomBouncingScrollPhysics(parent: buildParent(ancestor));
  }

  double frictionFactor(double overscrollFraction) =>
      0.52 * math.pow(1 - overscrollFraction, 2);

  @override
  double applyPhysicsToUserOffset(ScrollMetrics position, double offset) {
    assert(offset != 0.0);
    assert(position.minScrollExtent <= position.maxScrollExtent);

    if (!position.outOfRange) return offset;

    //final double overscrollPastStart = math.max(position.minScrollExtent - position.pixels, 0.0);
    final double overscrollPastEnd =
        math.max(position.pixels - position.maxScrollExtent, 0.0);
    final double overscrollPast =
        overscrollPastEnd; //math.max(overscrollPastStart, overscrollPastEnd);
    final bool easing = (overscrollPastEnd > 0.0 && offset > 0.0);

    final double friction = easing
        // Apply less resistance when easing the overscroll vs tensioning.
        ? frictionFactor(
            (overscrollPast - offset.abs()) / position.viewportDimension)
        : frictionFactor(overscrollPast / position.viewportDimension);
    final double direction = offset.sign;

    return direction * _applyFriction(overscrollPast, offset.abs(), friction);
  }

  static double _applyFriction(
      double extentOutside, double absDelta, double gamma) {
    assert(absDelta > 0);
    double total = 0.0;
    if (extentOutside > 0) {
      final double deltaToLimit = extentOutside / gamma;
      if (absDelta < deltaToLimit) return absDelta * gamma;
      total += extentOutside;
      absDelta -= deltaToLimit;
    }
    return total + absDelta;
  }

  @override
  double applyBoundaryConditions(ScrollMetrics position, double value) {
    if (value < position.pixels &&
        position.pixels <= position.minScrollExtent) {
      return value - position.pixels;
    }
    // if (position.maxScrollExtent <= position.pixels && position.pixels < value) // overscroll
    //   return value - position.pixels;
    if (value < position.minScrollExtent &&
        position.minScrollExtent < position.pixels) {
      return value - position.minScrollExtent;
    }
    // if (position.pixels < position.maxScrollExtent && position.maxScrollExtent < value) // hit bottom edge
    //   return value - position.maxScrollExtent;
    return 0.0;
  }

  @override
  Simulation? createBallisticSimulation(
      ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
    final Tolerance tolerance = this.tolerance;
    if (velocity.abs() >= tolerance.velocity || position.outOfRange) {
      return BouncingScrollSimulation(
        spring: spring,
        position: position.pixels,
        velocity: velocity,
        leadingExtent: position.minScrollExtent,
        trailingExtent: position.maxScrollExtent,
        tolerance: tolerance,
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  double get minFlingVelocity => kMinFlingVelocity * 2.0;

  @override
  double carriedMomentum(double existingVelocity) {
    return existingVelocity.sign *
        math.min(0.000816 * math.pow(existingVelocity.abs(), 1.967).toDouble(),
            40000.0);
  }

  // Eyeballed from observation to counter the effect of an unintended scroll
  // from the natural motion of lifting the finger after a scroll.
  @override
  double get dragStartDistanceMotionThreshold => 3.5;
}
```

source: https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet/issues/47#issuecomment-812623709

Answer (score 0):

Try below code using **BouncingScrollPhysics()** hope its help to you.

refer documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BouncingScrollPhysics-class.html)

```
physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just please add 'shrinkWrap: true' to ListView.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              destinationImage(),
              contentImage(),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```